# copy file or directory via scp from remote and locally change permissions afterwards

Tags: bash, scp, chmod

I would like to copy single files or directories recursively from a remote machine using scp and ssh-key and change the permissions of the file or the whole directory (with its contents) afterwards:

So far this alias worked for me:

```
alias scp='scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C -r $1 $2'
```

What i need now is something like:

```
alias scp='scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C -r $1 $2 && chmod -R 770 $copied_dir_or_file'
```

Comment: Use a function instead of the alias.

Comment: I already tried to get this working with a function, but failed. How should the function look like?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i finally managed to get what i need using a function:

```
scpr () { 
    file=$(basename $1);
    /bin/scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C -r $1 $2;
    find $file \( -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; \) 
}
```